# ReplayKitで全てのiOSの画面を録画できますか?

Tags: ios, swift

iosのreplayKitで全てのiOSの画面(自分が作成したアプリ内だけでなく、設定画面やホーム画面、他のアプリの画面なども)を録画することはできますか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

できません。

[ReplayKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ReplayKit/Reference/ReplayKit_Collection/)
The ReplayKit framework provides the ability to record audio and video **within an app** and share the resulting recording with other users through social media.

ReplayKitというのは、あなたのアプリのうちReplayKitに対応するように作られた特別な一部を録画可能にするフレームワークであって、あなたのアプリからiOSデバイスの任意の画面を録画できるようにするものではありません。

Answer (score 2):

iOS11で追加された、ReplayKit2では可能です。